# Property 'mask' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, mask

I recently was trying to use the jquery mask in my angular project, so i installed in my project with: `npm i jquery-mask-plugin`, so in my TS file i wrote:

```
ngOnInit() {
      $('.date').mask('11/11/1111');
      $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
      $('.date_time').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
      $('.cep').mask('00000-000');
      $('.phone').mask('0000-0000');
      $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
      $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
      $('.mixed').mask('AAA 000-S0S');
      $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
      $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
  }
```

Just as it is on the main site, but instead of `$(document).ready(function(e))` i preferred to use the `ngOnInit()` , but when i save, the console hit me with the error:

> "Property 'mask' does not exist on type 'Jquery'"

What am i doing wrong? I have to import on the appModule? I have to declare it in the angular.json? I have to import in the component file that i'm going to use? What should i do??
**Obs**: If there's any other mask for angular that you think it's better, please tell me :)

Comment: You should never NEVER **NEVER** mix jquery with angular. You would be better of using a [typescript / Angular  library](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask) to do that.

Comment: @Nicolas is correct, would upvote it 10x if I could. Why would you use two different javascript frameworks side by side, it is like using java and c# together.

Comment: Ow, good to hear that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the 'official' mask library for Angular 2+ is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask. I have used it on several occasions and it works quite well. You should import it in appModule and if you have lazy loaded modules that are also using the mask in them as well.